# ¿Como hacer que x funcion se aplique solo a un determinado ancho de pantalla con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo este script que cuando la pantalla es menor o igual a 800px, se activa una funcion que hace que el body tenga opacity al 60% y tenga un fadeOut lento el div .box1, cuando es mayor a 801px, se activa una funcion diferente que hace que el div .box1 cambie a color azul y tenga un slideUp lento ademas que el color de fondo del body tenga un gris claro. El problema es que, si yo estoy en una pantalla de 800px y doy click en el boton, se me aplica la funcion para ese ancho de pantalla, y si redimensiono a una pantalla mas grande, y vuelvo a clickear en el boton, un pedazo de la funcion de pantalla mas chica se activa en la pantalla mas grande y sucede lo mismo viceversamente. ¿Exite alguna forma de que las funciones se apliquen de acuerdo a la mediaquery establecida? gracias de antemano. NOTA: el div .box1 no debe cambiar a color azul cuando la pantalla es de 800 y el body debe tener opacidad cuando el ancho es mayor a 800 (es para diferenciar cambios de funciones)

```js
$(function(){
const changeResizeDesktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 801px)');

function changeStyles(){
    if (changeResizeDesktop.matches){
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('.box1').fadeIn();
        $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('.box1').css('background','darkblue').slideUp(4000);
        $('body').css('background','#ededed');      
        });     
    } else {
        $('.box1').add('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('.box1').slideDown();
        $('button').on('click', function(){
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
        $('.box1').fadeOut(4000);
        $('body').css('opacity','0.5'); 
        });
    }
}

changeStyles();
window.addEventListener('resize', changeStyles);

    });
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.box1{
height: 200px;
margin: 10px;
width: 20%;
background: darkred;
}
button{
background: darkred;
color: white;
border-radius: 8px;
line-height: 2;
padding: 0 3%;
margin: 10px;
border: none;
}
button:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<button>Toca el boton</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno la razón de tu problema es por como estas haciendo con la acción de tu botón.
Dale un **console.log(buton.click)** y verás que cada vez que haces click en el botón estas aumentándole funciones y funciones a tu botón, ósea primera vez que ejecutas la acción del botón tienes digamos el **if**, luego si cambias el tamaño de la pantalla para ejecutar el **else** tu botón tiene ya dos funciones que va ejecutar primero el **if** y **else**, luego si vuelve a cambiar el tamaño de la pantalla verás 3 funciones en tu console.log del botón, y así sucesivamente, y todas las funciones se ejecutan al hacer click por eso tienes ese comportamiento.

¿Qué debes hacer? -Mover la función del click a otro lado o retirar las funciones del botón antes de añadirle una nueva función.

Yo he movido tú código del botón a otra función:

```js
$(function(){
   const changeResizeDesktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 801px)');

   function changeStyles() {
      if (changeResizeDesktop.matches){
         $('body').removeAttr('style');
         $('.box1').fadeIn();
         /* Retiramos la función para declararla en otro lado
         $('button').on('click', function(){
            $('body').removeAttr('style');
            $('.box1').css('background','darkblue').slideUp(4000);
            $('body').css('background','#ededed');      
            console.log($('button').click);
         });
         */
      } else {
         $('.box1').add('body').removeAttr('style');
         $('.box1').slideDown();
         /* Retiramos la función para declararla en otro lado
         $('button').on('click', function(){
            $('body').removeAttr('style');
            $('.box1').fadeOut(4000);
            $('body').css('opacity','0.5');
            console.log($('button').click);
         });
         */
      }
   }
   
   // declaramos la función on click y verificamos el ancho de la patalla.
   $('button').on('click', function() {
      if (changeResizeDesktop.matches){
         $('body').removeAttr('style');
         $('.box1').css('background','darkblue').slideUp(4000);
         $('body').css('background','#ededed');
      } else {
         $('body').removeAttr('style');
         $('.box1').fadeOut(4000);
         $('body').css('opacity','0.5');
      }
   });

   changeStyles();
   window.addEventListener('resize', changeStyles);

});
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.box1{
 height: 200px;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 20%;
 background: darkred;
}
button{
 background: darkred;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 8px;
 line-height: 2;
 padding: 0 3%;
 margin: 10px;
 border: none;
}
button:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box1"></div>
<button>Toca el boton</button>
```

Comment: recién veo tu respuesta, efectivamente con lo que dices, agregé un console.log y pude notar q se me agregaba la funcion cada vez que hacia clic en el boton, tendré q tener en cuenta console.log para ir verificando que tan bien va el codigo, gracias por responder

Comment: Que bueno, finalmente como solucionaste tu problema? limpiando los atributos de funciones del elemento botón, o declarando una única función para el botón en un apartado distinto (la opción que te di).

Comment: lo solucione con la solucion que me diste, gracias crack.